# How to scan user activity in order to reset timer in Android

Tags: android, timer, user-interaction

I'm facing one issue and I cannot find the solution.

My application has a PIN code and I want to un-verify it after 2 minutes without any action from user. For instance user verified the PIN and than leave the phone on the table (with running application) and I want to un-verify the pin after 2 minutes.

Question is how to scan the user activity (it means touch anywhere on the screen or buttons). Of course I can scan the touch on active components (buttons etc) but I also want to scan the touch anywhere on the screen to reset the timer.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the activity's main layout's onTouchEvent to detect any touch gesture within the whole viewable area(which should fill the whole screen). just remember to return super.onTouchEvent to ensure that the other active components can still consume the event when they are touched separately.

Comment: Greate idea. It seems that only add clickable="true" and onClick="method" is enough. But what about dialog? do you have idea how to solve situation when dialog is shown and user click on the disabled par of the screen?

Comment: I think you need TouchInterceptor for that. <dialog's window>.setOnTouchInterceptor if i'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Override activity method [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29)

```
@overide
public void onUserInteraction() {
    //reset you timer here
     super.onUserInteraction();     
}
```